# Remote Desktop connection from one Windows 10 Pro PC to another

Tags: remote-access, windows-10

I have two windows 10 Pro machines in a small office environment. One's a desktop machine, the others a lap-top.

The desktop has been set up to allow remote connections, and whilst both machines are on the same WiFi network I can successfully use a Remote Desktop Connection from my laptop to remotely control my desktop - exactly what I want!

The problem is that when I use my laptop from another location (geographically separate i.e. client offices) I can no longer establish a remote desktop connection. What I've read so far seems to suggest I need a Remote Desktop Gateway.

Questions:- do I *have* to have a Remote Desktop Gateway to make a remote connection from an external network? If so, can a gateway be installed on Windows 10 Pro (and how). Or is there a simpler way of remote-controlling my home desktop?

(not sure if it's relevant, but I'm *not* using a VPN and my home desktop is has a pretty basic out-of-the box installation)

All help appreciated

---

UPDATE - I'd prefer to avoid a VPN if possible, my home desktop is basically a very large database that loads several Gbytes of data a day. If i put this on a VPN then all that data will have to come through the VPN which would exceed the data allowance for any of the free VPNs, so I'd have to get go for one of the paid-for versions.
All I actually want to be able to do is log on once every few days and check the database is still up!

Comment: the two different networks are two different LAN or they are also geographically separated?

Comment: @AtomiX84 - geographically separate

Comment: ok, then you have to port forward the 3389 port in you router (strongly not recommended) it is more safe to use a VPN instead.

Comment: Run a VPN server from your home network.

Comment: Just throwing this out there, but what about another free remote access solution like TeamViewer? Usually these services are free for home use and do not require port forwarding on your router.

Comment: @twconnell - I'll be honest, I've never heard of TeamViewer, but a quick google shows it's actually quite expensive (a lot more than a VPN!). Just spotted something called remotePc that does offer a properly free version that might do the trick - will investigate

Answer (score 3):

While the easiest solution would be to just port forward 3389 to your desktop this is highly inadvisable and would be a large security risk.

You need to configure a vpn to allow your laptop to access your LAN that your desktop is on. Depending on your router it may have an option to run an OpenVPN server and then you could install the client on your laptop and use that to connect when outside of your local network.

Comment: So Windows Server 2019 (or similar) is required for a Remote Desktop Gateway?